# Android ViewAnimator/ViewFlipper/ViewSwitcher and hardcoded value for setDisplayedChild

Tags: android, view, android-layout

I am going to work with one of:

- `ViewAnimator`
- `ViewFlipper`
- `ViewSwitcher`

All of them have a method `setDisplayedChild` to change a view from one to another.

Only argument of that method is `int whichChild` - a number of view in the view queue.

Is it possible to work with any sort of not hardcoded numbers ?

I want to be able to call:

```
setDisplayedChild(R.id.SettingsView)
```

instead of:

```
setDisplayedChild(3)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the indexOfChild(View child) method:

```
viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild( viewAnimator.indexOfChild( findViewById(R.id.SettingsView) ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

These classes are just ViewGroup extensions that keep the child list in and array of View.

You could easily extend whatever one you want to look through the list of views for the Id. 
(untested code follows)

```
class myFlipper extends ViewFlipper {

    public myFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    int getChildById(int id) {
        int childindex = -1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i<getChildCount()) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v.getId()==id) {
                childindex = i;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return childindex;
    }

    void setDisplayedChildById(int id) {
        int i = getChildById(id);
        if (i != -1) {
            setDisplayedChild(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use it in xml definition of UI ?

Comment: Sure.  you just use the full package name+class in place of <ViewFlipper> you use <com.xyz.MyFlipper>.  All of the other settings work the same.

Comment: Works like a charm - it is a great solution ! Thank you slund very much ! BTW - I've added `i++;` in your answer. ;)